# Accumulator server in OCB instance

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, accumulator

Orion Context Broker FIWARE Lab instance

How can I start the accumulator server in a FIWARE Lab instance?

Is it possible?

Comment: By "instance" you mean a VM running in the FIWARE Lab cloud? Do you have access (i.e. ssh) to that VM?

Comment: Yes, is a OCB VM. I have access to it. The problem is that I try to install the accumulator-server using: sudo yum install contextBroker. and it doesn't work.

Comment: The error that appears is: 
http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Fiware. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: You get that error as result of "sudo yum install contextBroker" ?

Comment: Yes, [centos@secureiot-2 ~]$ sudo yum install contextBroker
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, presto
Configurando el proceso de instalación
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.gadix.com
 * epel: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * extras: mirror.gadix.com
 * updates: mirror.gadix.com
http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Intentando con otro espejo.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Fiware. Please verify its path and try agai

Comment: But in that case the question is not "How to run the accumulator in FIWARE Lab VM" bug "How to install Context Broker in FIWARE Lab VM" as what the "sudo yum install contextBroker" attemps to do it to install ContextBroker. Or maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: You are right. My goal is to use the accumulator-server.

Comment: I want to start the accumulator server to capture notifications.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the accumulator, just download it from the github repositorio in [this link](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/scripts/accumulator-server.py).

You would need Flask dependency to run the accumulator. If Flask is not previously installed and you get an error about it when trying to run accumulator-server.py, then install it using pip:

```
pip install Flask
```

Comment: But the problem I think that is in relation with yum repositories because if I try to install pip or whatever the error is the same.

Comment: Ex: [centos@secureiot-2 ~]$ sudo yum install python-pip
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, presto
Configurando el proceso de instalación
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.gadix.com
 * epel: mirror.airenetworks.es
 * extras: mirror.gadix.com
 * updates: mirror.gadix.com
http://repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Intentando con otro espejo.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Fiware. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: pip is standard software, it is not provided by FIWARE repository. So, if you are not able to install pip using yum probably you have a more general problem related with yum or CentOS/RHEL system itself. In this case, I'd recommend you to post a separted question about the general problema with yum.